# Android AlertDialog Text Alignment

Tags: android, rss, android-alertdialog

I am creating an android app which pulls in RSS Feeds from here http://spaceflight1.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/cities/rss/index.cgi?country=United_Kingdom&region=England&city=Manchester

I had trouble with removing the < br/> tags from the RSS feed as i have it pulling into a AlertDialog Box but i managed to get it working with this code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String title = episode_titles.get(position);
String descrip = episode_description.get(position);
title = removeBr(title);
descrip = removeBr(descrip);


      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle(title);
      alertDialog.setMessage(descrip);

      alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        } }); 

      alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.android_icon);
      alertDialog.show();
    }


    private String removeBr(String str1){
      return str1.replaceAll("<br/>", "");
    }
```

Now the problem i have is that when i view the RSS feed description in my Alert Dialog box it seems that even though the < br/> have been told to show nothing they are still making the line of text move over to the right (image below) is there a way to get all the text aligned on the left so to say where the word November starts i want each line to start there.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trimming the strings before displaying them:

```
title = removeBr(title).trim();
descrip = removeBr(descrip).trim();
```

Later edit: True, I didn't notice that `descrip` also contains some tabs as well.

```
descrip = removeBr(descrip).replaceAll("\\t", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it seems to have worked partly it has fixed the top line but the rest are still in the same postion could you think of a fix. I ahve updated the image in the original post to reflect the changes. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you truly are a android Guru